# how to plot a Shinobi graph based on json data without key using objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, graph, shinobi

I am having problem, plotting json data in this structure below.

```
{"response":{"hash":"0fea72f2bea9820c18227a655b42fe66","resp_code":"GRAPH_RETRIEVED","code":200},"resultstats":{"record_count":46},"ana_uoms":["°C"],"data":[{"asset_id":204,"company_id":30,"asset_name":"WIF","stats":{"min":1.4,"max":6.9,"min_tstamps_count":1,"min_tstamps":["2015-03-17 08:30:00"],"max_tstamps":["2015-03-17 11:00:00","2015-03-17 11:30:00","2015-03-17 13:40:00","2015-03-17 14:50:00"],"mkt":5.91,"max_tstamps_count":4,"avg":5.8},"component_type":"ana_in","component_description":"WFt","site_name":"Kll","alarms":[],"sampling_rate":10,"region_name":"ll","component_id":8340,"company_name":"lb","uom":"°C","uom_decimal_places":1,"unit_sn":"3310","resolves":[],"records":[["2015-03-17 08:00",2.6],["2015-03-17 08:10",3.9],["2015-03-17 08:20",2.4],["2015-03-17 08:30",1.4],["2015-03-17 08:40",3.1],["2015-03-17 08:50",4.4],["2015-03-17 09:00",5.1],["2015-03-17 09:10",5.5],["2015-03-17 09:20",6.1],["2015-03-17 09:30",6.2],["2015-03-17 09:40",5.3],["2015-03-17 09:50",6.4],["2015-03-17 10:00",6.6],["2015-03-17 10:10",6.7],["2015-03-17 10:20",6.8],["2015-03-17 10:30",5.2],["2015-03-17 10:40",6.3],["2015-03-17 10:50",6.7],["2015-03-17 11:00",6.9],["2015-03-17 11:10",6],["2015-03-17 11:20",6.6],["2015-03-17 11:30",6.9],["2015-03-17 11:40",5.9],["2015-03-17 11:50",6.6],["2015-03-17 12:00",6.8],["2015-03-17 12:10",6.1],["2015-03-17 12:20",6.6],["2015-03-17 12:30",5.6],["2015-03-17 12:40",6.2],["2015-03-17 12:50",6.8],["2015-03-17 13:00",5.7],["2015-03-17 13:10",6.6],["2015-03-17 13:20",5.8],["2015-03-17 13:30",6.4],["2015-03-17 13:40",6.9],["2015-03-17 13:50",6],["2015-03-17 14:00",6.7],["2015-03-17 14:10",5.2],["2015-03-17 14:20",6.5],["2015-03-17 14:30",5.8],["2015-03-17 14:40",6.3],["2015-03-17 14:50",6.9],["2015-03-17 15:00",6.6],["2015-03-17 15:10",5.9],["2015-03-17 15:20",6.3],["2015-03-17 15:30",6.5]]},{"asset_id":204,"company_id":30,"asset_name":"Wft","stats":{"min":2.9,"max":6.8,"min_tstamps_count":1,"min_tstamps":["2015-03-17 08:30:00"],"max_tstamps":["2015-03-17 11:00:00","2015-03-17 11:30:00","2015-03-17 12:00:00","2015-03-17 13:40:00"],"mkt":5.8,"max_tstamps_count":4,"avg":5.7},"component_type":"ana_in","component_description":"WIF Right Back","site_name":"Ktore","alarms":[],"sampling_rate":10,"region_name":"Kano","component_id":8341,"company_name":"lls","uom":"°C","uom_decimal_places":1,"unit_sn":"3310","resolves":[],"records":[["2015-03-17 08:00",3.2],["2015-03-17 08:10",4.2],["2015-03-17 08:20",3.1],["2015-03-17 08:30",2.9],["2015-03-17 08:40",3.7],["2015-03-17 08:50",4.5],["2015-03-17 09:00",5.2],["2015-03-17 09:10",5.6],["2015-03-17 09:20",6.1],["2015-03-17 09:30",6.3],["2015-03-17 09:40",4.8],["2015-03-17 09:50",6.3],["2015-03-17 10:00",6.5],["2015-03-17 10:10",6.6],["2015-03-17 10:20",6.7],["2015-03-17 10:30",4.5],["2015-03-17 10:40",6.3],["2015-03-17 10:50",6.6],["2015-03-17 11:00",6.8],["2015-03-17 11:10",5.9],["2015-03-17 11:20",6.5],["2015-03-17 11:30",6.8],["2015-03-17 11:40",5.7],["2015-03-17 11:50",6.5],["2015-03-17 12:00",6.8],["2015-03-17 12:10",5.9],["2015-03-17 12:20",6.6],["2015-03-17 12:30",5],["2015-03-17 12:40",6.2],["2015-03-17 12:50",6.7],["2015-03-17 13:00",5.5],["2015-03-17 13:10",6.5],["2015-03-17 13:20",5.2],["2015-03-17 13:30",6.2],["2015-03-17 13:40",6.8],["2015-03-17 13:50",5.8],["2015-03-17 14:00",6.6],["2015-03-17 14:10",4.5],["2015-03-17 14:20",6.4],["2015-03-17 14:30",5.2],["2015-03-17 14:40",6.2],["2015-03-17 14:50",6.7],["2015-03-17 15:00",6.4],["2015-03-17 15:10",5.2],["2015-03-17 15:20",6.2],["2015-03-17 15:30",6.1]]}],"ana_thresholds":[["<1.0"],[">8.0"]],"parameters":{"end_date":"2015-03-17 15:30","start_date":"2015-03-17 08:00","sampling_rate":10}}
```

I am basically trying to use Shinobi graph library trial to plot this json data but I am totally clueless how to parse objects above. In the json I have the date-time and temperature values. I manage to see the parse response in my console. However the graph has no object data to plot because I am not passing any json values to the series since I don't know how its done. Please kind assist because I have not seen a similar question in stackoverflow.

Here is my code snippet.

```
- (void) loadData{
// Parse units offline from the webservice.
@try{

    NSString *delete = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
    NSString *logOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY URL"];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:logOut];
    NSLog(@"Asset list: %@", url);
    NSData *postData =[delete dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Reponse code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
        @try{
            NSError *error = nil;
       // NSMutableArray* jsonDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSDictionary *jsonDetails = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
            NSArray *graphData = [ jsonDetails objectForKey:@"records"];
             NSLog(@"Retrieving graph: %@", jsonDetails);

            for (NSDictionary* jsonPoint  in graphData) {
                SChartDataPoint* datapoint = [self dataPointForDate:jsonPoint[@"date"]
                                                           andValue:jsonPoint[@"temp"]];
                NSLog(@"SChart point: %@", datapoint);
                [_timeSeries addObject:datapoint];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *e){
            NSLog(@"Try catch block: %@", e);
        }
        @finally{
            // [self.tblRegion reloadData];
            NSLog(@"finally");
        }


    }

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sammyd's help, believe this a close answer to my question. The snippet below is almost perfect. The only thing is that I still need to change the dateformat to get the datapoints in the series.

```
{
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
        
            NSError *error = nil;
            jsonDetails = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray *keys = [jsonDetails allKeys];
        // values in foreach loop
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            // NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [jsonDetails objectForKey:key]);
            
            data = [jsonDetails objectForKey:@"data"];
            graphData = [data[0]objectForKey:@"records"];
            datapoint = [[SChartDataPoint alloc] init];
            // NSLog(@"Record for the graph: %@", graphData);
            // results = [jsonDetails objectForKey:@"resultstats"];
            // recordCount = [results objectForKey:@"record_count"];
            
        for (int i=0; i< [graphData count]; i++){
            NSArray *record = graphData[i];
            // NSLog(@"Record value: %@", record);
            datapoint.xValue = record[0]; // date
            NSLog(@"Date/time: %@", datapoint.xValue);
            datapoint.yValue = record[1]; // number
            NSLog(@"Temp: %@", datapoint.yValue);
            datapoint = [self dataPointForDate:datapoint.xValue
                                                       andValue:datapoint.yValue];
            
            NSLog(@"Adding datapoint to series: %@", datapoint);
            [_timeSeries addObject:datapoint];
        }
           
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the console out put. I'll not paste the whole console output because the json response and NSLog's I put for debugging purpose.You can see for some reason when I add datapoint objects to the series. datapoint.xValue is null hence I still don't see the graph in the app. I have changd the date format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm and here is my console output. Still no graph is plotted .

```html
TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] Adding datapoint to series: { index=0, x=2015-03-22 13:20:00 +0000, y=6.4, selected=N }
2015-03-23 07:49:01.682 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] Date/time: 2015-03-22 15:30
2015-03-23 07:49:01.683 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] Temp: 6.3
2015-03-23 07:49:01.685 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] Time/Date format: 2015-03-22 13:30:00 +0000
2015-03-23 07:49:01.685 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] Adding datapoint to series: { index=0, x=2015-03-22 13:30:00 +0000, y=6.3, selected=N }
2015-03-23 07:49:01.697 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] ShinobiCharts: Attempting to update axis data range with nil series min or max. Axis range not updated.
From: SChartDateTimeAxis at 0x15d64d10, axisRange = { 0.000000, 1.000000 }, defaultRange = { 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 }, maxRange = { 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 }
2015-03-23 07:49:01.698 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] ShinobiCharts: Attempting to update axis data range with nil series min or max. Axis range not updated.
From: SChartNumberAxis at 0x19c852e0, axisRange = { 0.000000, 1.000000 }, defaultRange = { 0.000000, 1.000000 }, maxRange = { 0.000000, 1.000000 }
```

I fixed the above error by following sammyd's suggestion answer;

```
    for (NSArray *record in graphData) {
            
            // NSArray *record = graphData[i];
            // NSLog(@"Record value: %@", record);
            NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[record objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSDate *date = [self dateFromString:dateString];
            datapoint.xValue = date; // date
            NSLog(@"Date/time: %@", datapoint.xValue);
            // NSString *date = datapoint.xValue;
            datapoint.yValue = record[1]; // number
            NSLog(@"Temp: %@", datapoint.yValue);
            datapoint = [self dataPointForDate:record[0]
                                            andValue:record[1]];
            
            NSLog(@"Adding datapoint to series: %@", datapoint);
            [_timeSeries addObject:datapoint];
        }
```

I am now happy and proceeding to follow Sammayd's blog tutorial on implementing the rand[SammyD's Blog](http://iwantmyreal.name/blog/2013/01/11/building-a-range-selector-with-shinobi-charts-part-i-linking-2-charts/).
See screenshots of the output. Thanks you all guys.
[image]

[image]

In portrait the graph looks not so pretty any suggestions are welcome. Mind you the data plotted here is about 4000+ data.I think it can be better scaled, please share what I can do to make the graph more representable like the iOS stock App.

Answer (score 1):

A **shinobichart** uses the same model as `UITableView` to provide data - in that it uses a datasource object. You need an object that conforms to the `SChartDatasource` protocol - which has 4 required methods to provide the data to the chart. These include providing the number of data points and the data points themselves (amongst others).

If you save the datapoints you are creating into an array then you can then pass them to the chart in the appropriate `SChartDatasource` methods.

Rather than repeat it here, I'll refer you to the **shinobicharts** quick start guide, which runs through the basics of providing data to a chart:

[shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiCharts/2.7.0/Premium/Normal/user_guide.html](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiCharts/2.7.0/Premium/Normal/user_guide.html#Quick%20Start%20Guide)

The JSON structure you have here has a records field with the following structure:

```
"records":[["2015-03-17 08:00",2.6],["2015-03-17 08:10",3.9],...
```

This is an array of arrays - i.e. each data point is represented by an array - with the first element being the date, and the second element the value.

You need to update the following:

```
for (NSDictionary* jsonPoint  in graphData) {
    SChartDataPoint* datapoint = [self dataPointForDate:jsonPoint[@"date"]
                                               andValue:jsonPoint[@"temp"]];
    NSLog(@"SChart point: %@", datapoint);
    [_timeSeries addObject:datapoint];
}
```

Instead of `NSDictionary` objects, you actually have `NSArray`:

```
for (NSArray* jsonPoint  in graphData) {
    SChartDataPoint* datapoint = [self dataPointForDate:jsonPoint[0]
                                               andValue:jsonPoint[1]];
    NSLog(@"SChart point: %@", datapoint);
    [_timeSeries addObject:datapoint];
}
```

Note that you *might* have to parse the date value from an `NSString` to an `NSDate` - depending on what your `dataPointForDate:andValue:` method does. You can do this with `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Sammyd, thanks for your response. I looked at the guide and sample time series iOS code but. My issue is the jso structure I have from the webservice. You can help me with how to parse a json with no key, I'll appreciate that.

Comment: I still cannot save the datapoints , because i'm failing to comsume json objects, with no key.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "json objects with no key". Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you take a look at the json response in the question you will notice the json structure has no key to identify objects as date or temperature values. Question is how do I plot this json like this with shinobicharts?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear to me, so no I don't. That's why I asked you whether you could elaborate.

Comment: In this json I want to plot date/time against temperature value. How do I consume the json objects in this structure in objective-c :,"records":[["2015-03-17 08:00",2.6],["2015-03-17 08:10",3.9],["2015-03-17 08:20",2.4]]

Comment: Sammyd, do I make sense what I want to plot, because I don't know objective-c and I am considering buying shinobicharts if I can plot this with you sample android and iOS timeseries. Which is not working so far.hence I need your help on this

Comment: Hello Sammy, I'm urgently looking for solution for this because I will be more than willing to pay for the premium license for shinobicharts. Please kindly assist

Comment: Ah ok - I see your problem. I shall update my answer

Comment: Thank you sammyd. I appreciate it. I tried getting all the json dictionary keys from the response and  records is not included.

Comment: Hi Sammy did you manage to come up with an answer as I'm still battling on my side.

Comment: Take a look at the structure. You need to walk the structure you sent to find the "records" field. something like:

NSArray *data = [jsonDetails objectForKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary *graphData = [data[0] objectForKey:@"records"];

Comment: Pretty clear explanation, sammy. Now in the console I get all the records from json. I guess just need to retrieve object 0 and 1 then add them to the chart datapoint. With rusty objective-c I assume I'll write something like this. NSdate *date = graphData[0]; // to get the date from records NSNumber *temperature = graphData[1]; // to get the temperature from the records. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I wonder if I should put this in a for loop to get index 0 and 1 from records until finish parsing all the data and then only add the data to the series ???

Answer (score 1):

From your json structure i guess that your chart should have 2 series. One for data[0] and one for data[1]. If i am wrong you can edit my answer to satisfy your needs.

First of all you could create 2 helpful classes. The first one is "ChartPoint":

```
@interface ChartPoint : NSObject

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSDate *date;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *value;

@end
```

The second is "ChartData":

```
@interface ChartData : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *siteName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *chartPoints;

@end
```

which will hold the information about your series. The title of your series and a number of ChartPoints.

The next step is to set up the chart. You can see how this is done in ShinobiChart examples. Here is some code for that:

```
-(void)setUpChart
{
    schart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.chartView.bounds];
    schart.delegate=self;
    schart.datasource = self;
    schart.autoresizingMask =  ~UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    schart.licenseKey = @"your licence";

    schart.legend.hidden=NO;

    //X AXIS CONFIGURATION
    SChartDateTimeAxis *xAxis = [[SChartDateTimeAxis alloc] init];
    xAxis.style.interSeriesPadding = @0;

    xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showLabels = YES;
    xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks  = YES;

    schart.xAxis = xAxis;

    //Y AXIS CONFIGURATION
    SChartAxis *yAxis = [[SChartNumberAxis alloc] init];

    yAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines=YES;

    yAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showLabels = YES;
    yAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks  = YES;

    schart.yAxis = yAxis;

    // add to the view
    [self.chartView addSubview:schart];
}
```

After that you need to parse your server's response and create instances of the above helpful classes. If you will plot a number of series, your view controller should hold an array "chartSeries" with "ChartData" objects. After you deserialise the response to an NSDictionary you should do the following:

```
-(void)parseResponse:(NSDictionary*)response
{
    chartSeries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

    NSArray *data = [response objectForKey:@"data"];

    for (NSDictionary *d in data)
    {
        NSString *sitename = [d objectForKey:@"site_name"];
        NSArray *records = [d objectForKey:@"records"];

        ChartData *cd = [[ChartData alloc] init];
        cd.siteName=sitename;
        cd.chartPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSArray *r in records)
        {
            NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[r objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];


            NSNumber *value = [r objectAtIndex:1];

            ChartPoint *point =[[ChartPoint alloc] init];
            point.date=date;
            point.value = value;

            [cd.chartPoints addObject:point];
        }


        [chartSeries addObject:cd];
    }

    [schart reloadData];
    [schart redrawChart];
}
```

You see that after parsing is complete, you must reload the chart data and redraw it. This is because of the SChartDatasource protocol just like the UITableViews.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSeriesInSChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart
{
    return chartSeries.count;
}

- (NSInteger)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart numberOfDataPointsForSeriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)seriesIndex
{
    ChartData * data  = [chartSeries objectAtIndex:seriesIndex];
    return data.chartPoints.count;
}

-(SChartSeries *)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart seriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    ChartData * data  = [chartSeries objectAtIndex:index];

    SChartColumnSeries *columnSeries = [[SChartColumnSeries alloc] init];
    columnSeries.title=data.siteName;

    return columnSeries;
}

- (id<SChartData>)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart dataPointAtIndex:(NSInteger)dataIndex forSeriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)seriesIndex
{
    ChartData * data  = [chartSeries objectAtIndex:seriesIndex];
    ChartPoint *point = [data.chartPoints objectAtIndex:dataIndex];

    SChartDataPoint *dp = [[SChartDataPoint alloc] init];

    dp.yValue = point.value;
    dp.xValue =point.date;

    return dp;
}
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Kyriakosmp's thanks for your answer, but the json is a 1 series. Only need to plot the records not the sites. I will edit your answer where necessary, because my answer still don't give me graph but in console my datapoint are adding to the series. Maybe I need to reload and redraw the series as you pointed out.

Comment: The parsing the json is sorted Kyriakosmp, sammyd. The issue now is getting the graph to show the lineseries, because if you look at  my console log, this is the result I get as posted in my edited answer; TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] Adding datapoint to series: { index=0, x=2015-03-22 13:30:00 +0000, y=6.3, selected=N }
2015-03-23 07:49:01.697 TimeSeriesChart[952:468171] ShinobiCharts: Attempting to update axis data range with nil series min or max. Axis range not updated.

Comment: I believe your problem was the way you parsed the date. From your edit i see you used my approach but you mentioned sammyd. If my answer did help you to parse the json correctly and display the data you could vote it up and mark as accepted.

Comment: The date format was the issue and adding objects to the series. I could say I used both Sammyd, and your approach to get the solution right. Thanks alot mates